# swiftui, animation applied to parent effect child animation

Tags: animation, swiftui

RectangleView has a slide animation, his child TextView has a rotation animation. I suppose that RectangleView with his child(TextView) as a whole slide(easeInOut) into screen when Go! pressed, and TextView rotate(linear) forever. But in fact, the child TextView separates from his parent, rotating(linear) and sliding(linear), and repeats forever.

why animation applied to parent effect child animation?

```
struct AnimationTestView: View {
    @State private var go = false
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Go!") {
                go.toggle()
            }
            if go {
                RectangleView()
                    .transition(.slide)
                    .animation(.easeInOut)
            }
        }.navigationTitle("Animation Test")
    }
}

struct RectangleView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Rectangle()
            .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
            .foregroundColor(.pink)
            .overlay(TextView())
    }
}

struct TextView: View {
    @State private var animationRotating: Bool = false
    let animation = Animation.linear(duration: 3.0).repeatForever(autoreverses: false)
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("Test")
            .foregroundColor(.blue)
            .rotationEffect(.degrees(animationRotating ? 360 : 0))
            .animation(animation)
            .onAppear { animationRotating = true }
            .onDisappear { animationRotating = false }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If there are several simultaneous animations the generic solution (in majority of cases) is to use explicit state value for each.

So here is a corrected code (tested with Xcode 12.1 / iOS 14.1, use Simulator or Device, Preview renders some transitions incorrectly)

[image: demo]

```
struct AnimationTestView: View {
    @State private var go = false
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Go!") {
                go.toggle()
            }
                VStack {      // container needed for correct transition !!
                    if go {
                         RectangleView()
                              .transition(.slide)
                    }
                }.animation(.easeInOut, value: go)    // << here !!
        }.navigationTitle("Animation Test")
    }
}

struct RectangleView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Rectangle()
            .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
            .foregroundColor(.pink)
            .overlay(TextView())
    }
}

struct TextView: View {
    @State private var animationRotating: Bool = false
    let animation = Animation.linear(duration: 3.0).repeatForever(autoreverses: false)
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("Test")
            .foregroundColor(.blue)
            .rotationEffect(.degrees(animationRotating ? 360 : 0))
            .animation(animation, value: animationRotating)          // << here !!
            .onAppear { animationRotating = true }
            .onDisappear { animationRotating = false }
    }
}
```

Comment: Now the TextView has its own state. RectangleView with TextView slide into screen in 3 seconds, but state of TextView changed after a second while silding. Now you can see TextView stops sliding, go to the destination at once. I have append the demo code above.

Comment: It is different question. One question - one answer.

Comment: OK, I will new a Q. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65614683/swiftui-animation-applied-to-parent-effect-child-animationpart-ii