# SwiftUI: view with animation jumps to destination when state changed

Tags: animation, swiftui

RectangleView with TextView slide into screen in 3 seconds, but state of TextView changed after a second while sliding. Now you can see TextView stops sliding, jumps to the destination at once.

I Just want the RectangleView with the TextView as a whole when sliding, and do not change TextView's position whatever it rotates or keeps still when state changed.

[image: demo gif]

```
import SwiftUI

struct RotationEnvironmentKey: EnvironmentKey {
    static let defaultValue: Bool = false
}

extension EnvironmentValues {
    var rotation: Bool {
        get { return self[RotationEnvironmentKey] }
        set { self[RotationEnvironmentKey] = newValue }
    }
}

struct AnimationTestView: View {
    @State private var go = false
    @State private var rotation = false
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Go!") {
                go.toggle()
                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1.0) {
                    rotation.toggle()
                    print("set rotation = \(rotation)")
                }
            }
            Group {
                if go {
                    RectangleView()
                        .transition(.slide)
                        .environment(\.rotation, rotation)
                }
            }.animation(.easeInOut(duration: 3.0), value: go)
        }.navigationTitle("Animation Test")
    }
}

struct RectangleView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Rectangle()
            .frame(width: 200, height: 100)
            .foregroundColor(.pink)
            .overlay(TextView())
    }
}

struct TextView: View {
    @Environment(\.rotation) var rotation
    @State private var animationRotating: Bool = false
    let animation = Animation.linear(duration: 3.0).repeatForever(autoreverses: false)
    
    var body: some View {
        print("refresh, rotation = \(rotation)"); return
        HStack {
            Spacer()
            if rotation {
                Text("R")
                    .foregroundColor(.blue)
                    .rotationEffect(.degrees(animationRotating ? 360 : 0))
                    .animation(animation, value: animationRotating)
                    .onAppear { animationRotating = true }
                    .onDisappear { animationRotating = false }
            } else {
                Text("S")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: FIXED: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65614683/swiftui-animation-applied-to-parent-effect-child-animationpart-ii

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now, after WWDC, apple provides a function geometryGroup to solve this kind problem.

Answer (score 1):

It because of view is recreated use delay. Remove `DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter` also use one single bool var for animation. No required for both.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var go = false
    @State private var rotation = false
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Go!") {
                go.toggle()
                rotation.toggle() //<-- Here
                
            }
            Group {
                if go {
                    RectangleView()
                        .transition(.slide)
                        .environment(\.rotation, rotation)
                }
            }.animation(.easeInOut(duration: 3.0), value: go)
        }.navigationTitle("Animation Test")
    }
}

struct RectangleView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Rectangle()
            .frame(width: 200, height: 100)
            .foregroundColor(.pink)
            .overlay(TextView())
    }
}

struct TextView: View {
    @Environment(\.rotation) var rotation
    @State private var animationRotating: Bool = false
    let animation = Animation.linear(duration: 3.0).repeatForever(autoreverses: false)
    
    var body: some View {
        print("refresh, rotation = \(rotation)"); return
        HStack {
            Spacer()
            if rotation {
                Text("R")
                    .foregroundColor(.blue)
                    .rotationEffect(.degrees(animationRotating ? 360 : 0))
                    .animation(animation.delay(1.0), value: animationRotating) //<-- here
                    .onAppear { animationRotating = true }
                    .onDisappear { animationRotating = false }
            } else {
                Text("S")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit:**

You are also changing the text with animation. For this, you need to change your body code.

```
@State private var opacity: Double = 1

var body: some View {
        print("refresh, rotation = \(rotation)"); return
            Text("R")
            .foregroundColor(.blue)
            .rotationEffect(.degrees(animationRotating ? 360 : 0))
            .animation(animation.delay(1.0), value: animationRotating) //<-- here
            .opacity(!animationRotating ? opacity : 0)
            .onAppear {
                animationRotating = true
                opacity = 1
            }
            .onDisappear {
                animationRotating = false
                opacity = 0
            }
            .overlay(Text("S")
                        .opacity(animationRotating ? opacity : 0))
            .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .trailing)
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, but you misunderstand me. Using DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter just simulates a state change. I don't know when rotation happened, just while sliding. A outer publisher cause to rotation state changed. it's not designed.

Comment: So is there any missing in my answer code ?

Comment: I mean something happened while sliding, cause to TextView need rotate. At this time, TextView jumps to the destination at once (see GIF), but I don't want this, I want TextView slide and rotate. How to fix it?

Comment: Okay you want both slide and rotate at the same time. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, and I want TextView has frozen position with Rectangleview, not seperated.